# SSIS Google Analytics Source Error

Tags: sql-server, google-analytics, ssis

I am using SSIS Google Analytics Source to get the data from Google Analytics to Sqlserver. I am getting the below error after entering the Access Token information. Please help me with this one.

> The service analytics has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   Quota Error: User Rate Limit Exceeded. [403]
>   Errors [
>       Message[Quota Error: User Rate Limit Exceeded.] Location[ - ] Reason[userRateLimitExceeded] Domain[global]
>   ]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPYYU.png)

Comment: The message seems pretty clear, you are banned from issueing more requests (hence the 403 status) because you met the API limits (User Rate Limit exceeded). Do fewer requests or get in touch with Google to see if your limits can be raised. Or wait until the next day when the limits are reset.

Comment: As the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/errors#standard_errors) states: `userRateLimitExceeded` Indicates that the user rate limit has been exceeded. The maximum rate limit is 10 qps per IP address. The default value set in Google Developers Console is 1 qps per IP address. You can increase this limit in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) to a maximum of 10 qps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply's. I am new to Google Analytics. I am not sure how to check the rate limit and exceed it. Can anyone please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: Also do i need to change any setting on the Google Analytics developers console before using SSIS Google Analytics Source. Please help me on this one.